# Cursor performance issue on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a legacy stored procedure trying to create a cursor to go through each row from a query. The performance is pretty bad. Then I check the query plan and most of the cost (> 47%) is on an object `[tempdb].[CWT_PrimaryKey]`. This object is created by cursor created in the stored procedure. Not sure how to improve performance for this case as there is no way to do anything on this object in `tempdb` created by SQL Server.

The pseudo-code in stored procedure like:

```
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION

  declare mycusorr local fast_forward
        for SELECT *  From MyTab Where a=b;
  open mycusorr; 
  fetch next from mycusorr into @v1, @v2, ...;

  while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
      --some query to check rules from different tables
      Update AnotherTab Set column=value where id = @v1;
      if (there is error)
         insert error to error user log table;

  End

  close mycusorr; 
  deallocate mycusorr; 

  COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  close mycusorr; 
  deallocate mycusorr; 
  SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;    
  ROLLBACK TRAN;    
END CATCH
```

There is no primary key on `MyTab`, but index created on the columns used in condition.

There are about 10,000 rows from `Mytab`. Run the stored procedure take more than 3 hours and even not finished. If I remove transaction from stored procedure, it will be fast.

When I check lock with `SP_lock`, there are more than 10 thousand X or IX lock on key or page for the table with update clause in loop.

Comment: What's happening within the loop part? 99% f the time a cursor can be re-written as a set-based solution. The only way to do that here is if you provide us with all the code

Comment: with the loop, just try to update another table with the data from the cursor.

Comment: If you provide your **actual** code I might be able to help. Without it the answer to the question is simply: "re-write to not use a cursor".

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, but why do you need a cursor in the 1st place? The update you are trying to do can be easily done in 1 single update statement with a join between `MyTab` and `AnotherTab` tables.

Comment: Why are you using a cursor for this? And why are you only bothering to close / deallocate if you enter the catch block?

Comment: I think the problem will be found from the "..."'s.  Should you replace those with real code, you may find your problem and maybe even a real answer here!

Comment: thanks, guys. the code is pretty long and I can't post it here. Actually, there are more than 1 query in the loop to follow the business rule and there is another simple insert for any error message. The cursor can't be replaced with a single update clause.

Comment: If it's too long to post here, then it's too long for us to solve. Essentially, I would be very, very, very surprised if you need a cursor for this, but without knowing the details that you refuse to post, the best answers you're going to get will be equally non-specific.

Comment: And yes, you will have a lot of locks because you're performing a large number of individual selects, updates and inserts in a single transaction. This is how locking works, and this is how you WANT locking to work. (Not that I'm endorsing your current approach, but in general.)

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
UPDATE t SET t.column = m.value
  FROM dbo.AnotherTab AS t
  INNER JOIN dbo.MyTab AS m
  ON t.id = ... no idea what the join criteria is because your cursor uses SELECT *
  WHERE m.a = m.b; -- I also don't think this is described well enough to guess
```

You can get a much, much, much better answer if you provide real code instead of pseudo-code.

Comment: +1 for as good a guess as can be achieved with the details provided.